# Conditional parameters while using factory pattern

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, algorithm, design-patterns

I was using old fashioned functions to process payroll but now I am moving it to a web-app with more features such as adjustable settings in the processing of the payroll.

Currently in the middle of reading about design patterns and decided to try to implement the factory pattern in one of my projects modules though I am slightly stuck. The goal is to apply conditional parameters to a classes attribute.

To give an idea of how my old function looked it simply converting excel files to dataframes using pandas `read_excel()` method:

```
def read_excel_files():
    df_stylist_analysis = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('stylist_analysis').stylist_analysis.path,
        sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=4)
    df_tips = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('tips_by_employee').tips_by_employee.path,
        sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=0)
    df_hours1 = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('hours_week_1').hours_week_1.path,
        header=None, skiprows=5)
    df_hours2 = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('hours_week_2').hours_week_2.path,
        header=None, skiprows=5)
    df_retention = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('client_retention').client_retention.path,
        sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=8)
    df_efficiency = pd.read_excel(
        Reports.objects.latest('employee_service_efficiency').employee_service_efficiency.path,
        sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=5)
    return df_stylist_analysis, df_tips, df_hours1, df_hours2, df_retention, df_efficiency
```

As you can see there are different amounts of rows being skipped on each file.

Currently I am trying to implement an Excel factory I wrote in place of the function so that it can handle several Excel file types:

```
class XLSDataExtractor:
    def __init__(self, filepath, rows):
        self.data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=rows)

    @property
    def parsed_data(self):
        return self.data


class XLSXDataExtractor:
    def __init__(self, filepath, rows):
        self.data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=rows)

    @property
    def parsed_data(self):
        return self.data


def data_extraction_factory(filepath):
    if filepath.endswith('xls'):
        extractor = XLSDataExtractor
    elif filepath.endswith('xlsx'):
        extractor = XLSXDataExtractor
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot open {filepath}')
    return extractor(filepath)


def extract_data_from(filepath):
    factory_obj = None
    try:
        factory_obj = data_extraction_factory(filepath)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    return factory_obj


def rows():
    #  if file name == human1 and filepath.endswith('xls') return 4
    #  if file name == human1 and filepath.endswith('xlsx') return 1
```

As you can see I need to pass in the `rows` as a parameter to the class attributes (I think). How can I implement this? I am having a bit of a struggle getting past this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can write like this:

```
def data_extraction_factory(filepath, rows=0):
    if filepath.endswith('xls'):
        extractor = XLSDataExtractor
    elif filepath.endswith('xlsx'):
        extractor = XLSXDataExtractor
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot open {filepath}')
    return extractor(filepath, rows)


def extract_data_from(filepath, rows=0):
    factory_obj = None
    try:
        factory_obj = data_extraction_factory(filepath, rows)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    return factory_obj
```

Here I am sending `rows` as keyword argument. So you can call `data_extraction_factory`, `extract_data_from` with or without `rows` argument.

Also:

> I need to pass in the rows as a parameter to the class attributes (I think)

That is not true. They are object attributes because you are passing them through `__init__` function. Means when an object of those classes are initiated, like `file_object=XLSXDataExtractor(...)`, then the `__init__` function is being called, so there you need to pass the value of rows.

---

### Update based on comment from OP

```
def data_extraction_factory(filepath, **kwargs):
    if filepath.endswith('xls'):
        extractor = XLSDataExtractor
    elif filepath.endswith('xlsx'):
        extractor = XLSXDataExtractor
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot open {filepath}')
    return extractor(filepath, **kwargs)


def extract_data_from(filepath, **kwargs):
    factory_obj = None
    try:
        factory_obj = data_extraction_factory(filepath, **kwargs)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    return factory_obj
```

Comment: I like the idea of using kwargs here. I had not realized that if you set the kwarg to `=0` that it would not require the argument. One thing I am not thrilled about is having to write `rows` all over the place. It feels like it doesn't follow the DRY principle.

Comment: another idea is to use `**kwargs`, you can pass any value as kwargs. example usage  `extract_data_from('/abc.xls', rows=12)`. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Yes, that feels much better and allows for flexibility. I am going to play around and see how I can get it to work better.